# Time duration with lack of formatting from excel behaving strangely in R

Tags: r, time

I have data in an excel spreadsheet, I'm importing it using `XLConnect`.

One column has duration data that was recorded like this: m:ss 
R is displaying it as a strange date.

Here's a sample of my data:

```
2:21
6:08
0:39
13:51
```

Here's a how R is interpreting it:

```
"1899-12-31 02:21:00"
"1899-12-31 06:08:00"
"1899-12-31 00:39:00"
"1899-12-31 13:51:00"
```

Any idea how I can get are to interpret it as duration of m:ss?

EDIT: I want to compare, graph, and preform some mathematics on these times. Any idea

Comment: strftime( times, format="%H:%M:%S" )

Comment: Are you using RStudio?

Comment: Yes, @Salman I'm using RStudio 1.0.143

Answer (score 1):

What about:
If you want to manipulate them as time, you can try this:

```
u <- c('2:21','6:08','0:39','13:51')
strptime(u,'%M:%S')
[1] "2018-08-30 00:02:21 CEST" "2018-08-30 00:06:08 CEST" "2018-08-30 00:00:39 CEST" "2018-08-30 00:13:51 CEST"
```

So you can do also operations like algebraic sums:

```
strptime(u,'%M:%S')-strptime(u[2],'%M:%S')
Time differences in secs
[1] -227    0 -329  463
```

If you want simply a character vector instead, you can trim it a bit:

```
substr(strptime(u,'%M:%S'),15,19)
[1] "02:21" "06:08" "00:39" "13:51"
```

or:

```
format(strptime(u,'%M:%S'), '%M:%S')
[1] "02:21" "06:08" "00:39" "13:51"
```

Lastly if you want the decimal of the minutes only if exists, you can try this:

```
ifelse(
substr(strptime(u,'%M:%S'),15,15)==0,
    substr(strptime(u,'%M:%S'),16,19),
    substr(strptime(u,'%M:%S'),15,19))
 [1] "2:21"  "6:08"  "0:39"  "13:51"
```

**EDIT**

If you want the 60 scales like times,  the option one is fine for plots:

```
 u <- c('2:21','6:08','0:39','13:51')
    strptime(u,'%M:%S')
    [1] "2018-08-30 00:02:21 CEST" "2018-08-30 00:06:08 CEST" "2018-08-30 00:00:39 CEST" "2018-08-30 00:13:51 CEST"
plot(x=c(1,2,3,4),strptime(u,'%M:%S'))
```

If you prefere a decimal scale, you can convert it:

```
sapply(strsplit(u,":"),
  function(x) {
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    x[1]+x[2]/60
    })

[1]  2.350000  6.133333  0.650000 13.850000
```

Comment: Thanks @s_t my intention is to graph and compare them. Perhaps average them as well. The last option's description seems to match what I'm trying to do (though I may be understanding it wrong, the output doesn't match what I'd expect). Express times as minute decimals, eg. 1:30 becomes 1.5 --

I'm trying your examples to bring some clarity.

Comment: Yes because it should be a string the last result so you cannot make operations. You need them to make operations? And convert all to a decimal scale rather than a sixty scale like time?

Comment: I figured it out, your post helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what was going on, but R was interpreting the dates as strings. When I attempted to convert them to dates I received an error:

```
> typeof(as.POSIXct(td$Time.on.Task))
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I realized I had character strings, so I used some of the techniques highlighted by @t_s in his answer (many thanks!).

First step was to issolate the time bit from the rest of the date-like string.

```
times <- substr(td$Time.on.Task, 12,16)
[1] "02:21" "06:08" "00:39" "13:51"
```

Next I turned them into decimal numbers, based in minutes, using the apply function and some simple math.

```
td$Minutes <- sapply(strsplit(times,":"),
                function(x) {
                  x <- as.numeric(x)
                  x[1]+x[2]/60
                })
[1] 2.35  6.13  0.65 13.85
```

And I have what I need to continue working.

Comment: We are arrived to the same conclusion, glad you've solved.